# Error in starting service (Service on the local computer and then stopped automatically)

Tags: c#, windows-services

I installed a Windows serivce that fetches has to fetch some strings from the App.Config file by the following method in `OnStart` - `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stringName"];`
Inside the App.Config, I also have a `source` defined for the log file which I use to write to my log file.

However, as I successfully install my service and try to start it from `Serivce Control Explorer` inside `My Computer -> Manage - > Device Manager`, I get a message saying

`The service on the local computer and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if not used by toher applications`

Inside the Windows Event Viewer, I get the following error detail (perhaps there is an exception thrown while starting the service)

Here's the error detail for the same:

```
Service cannot be started. System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section add. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\ServiceSetup\ServiceChecker.exe.Config line 3)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Dia...
```

The above detail shows error detail related to `.exe.config` file of the service. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the service and the installation Account for the serivce is set as `Local system` which has broad system previliges.

my App.Config in the project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
<appSettings>
      <add key="UtilName" value="sample.exe"/>
      <add key="App1" value="MyApp"/>
      <add key="App1E" value="MyApp.exe"/>
      <add key="App2" value="MyApp2"/>
      <add key="App2E" value="MyApp2.exe" />
      <add key="AppDirectory" value="Company\MyProject" />
      <add key="CMDArgs" value="\start"/>
</appSettings>    
      <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
          <source name="ServiceTrace" switchName="ServiceTraceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
            <listeners>
              <add name="ServiceLog" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="servicetrace.log"/>
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
          <add name="ServiceTraceSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4"></trace>
      </system.diagnostics>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your config, it seems the error is there.

Comment: @Adriano: Added the Config file text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that your app.config (or .exe.config) contains an unrecognized section. The error message usually says something like

> Unrecognized configuration section 'section name'

so i assume that you just added your config values without the needed  parent element. The element has to be added as a child element of the  section. Make sure it looks something like this:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="MyKey" value="MyValue" />
   </appSettings>
   ...some more configuration...
</configuration>
```

Comment: In the `Windows Service` project, if the app.config project is added, by default there is not `AppSettings` section inside this. Perhpas that might be problem. Checking

Comment: I added the `appSettings` that was missing earlier. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the service but no luck. Getting the same error again in the eveng viewer again. Editted the post to shows `appSettings section in the exe.Config` as well

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling won't change anything. Are you sure the .config file your exe is using is the one you edited?

Comment: Yes, the new .exe.config appears in the `bin\Debug` folder which is then added to the primary output of my setup project from where I install the service.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your .config file, per the error:

```
Unrecognized configuration section add.
```

This indicates you probably missed an outer section in your config file.  Should look like:

```
<section>
    <add ... >
</section>
```

Comment: Added the `app.Config` file in the post